# php script execution for heavy script file

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

i have a project which i develop in php framework named codeigniter. I have a script file in it which creates 30,0000 pdfs of db records for my client. the problem is that i have to run code in chunks. Because it gives errors, some time server time out, some time memory out of sync, I fixed all errors by changing in php.ini but in vain. Because I still have to make pdfs in chunks by using limit with 7000 ofset. IF I increase Limit offset it fails to run and gives me error. It's very hard to sit upto 30,0000 record and generate pdf on them. I just want that I run within one single chunk. Please give me solution. I really need it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running your PHP scripts from the CLI?

Comment: 30k or 300k that's a lot of resources to make that many pdf's. you need to loop and free resource as you go. it will still take hours (days?)

Comment: how are you running/calling your script? From a browser? command line?

Comment: Adnan, i am running it from a browser

Comment: Okay, so here's a hack/patch solution. Let your script echo this after it finishes the chunk (the 7000 offset) `echo '<script>window.location="thispage.php?offset="', $new_offset ,'</script>'`

Comment: ouch we get 28 pdf pages a second on 8 cores so 30 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using separate shell script for this, or if you insist on using a PHP script, use that as you would use a shell script. You can just "fire and forget" the script, so it would run on the background, without it affecting anything else and without it eating resources off your web application. That would be something like:

```
shell_exec('yourscript.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

or with php script

```
shell_exec('php yourscript.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

Note that in the above, I'm redirecting both stdout and stderr to null. If you wan't them, you'd rather redirect them to somewhere else.

Comment: EIS Dear, can you explain it, how can i do that.

Comment: @StromMan which part you have problems with?

Comment: Dear EIS, I make file on my root directory, I copy ur mantion code line with some modification shell_exec('php test.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &'); but it did not give any output please hlep me out how it works. Coz I dont know how it will work. thanks in advance

Comment: @StromMan like explained, the code redirects both stdout and stderr output to null. If you want to see that output, redirect it to where you want to see it.